# Excel Import using Laravel Hosted in AWS Lambda giving error 'touch(): Unable to create file because Read-only file system

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I am trying to import an excel sheet in Laravel, hosted in AWS Lambda and I am getting error

```
touch(): Unable to create file /var/task/storage/framework/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-ToQHNqV18ybdHCmqQFJKidLr5dSsWSUe.xlsx because Read-only file system
```

My code to import is

```
Excel::toArray(new ClientCompanyImport, $request->file('sales_accounts_sheet'));
```

Then I tried to mention the disc name as third parameter as

```
Excel::toArray(new ClientCompanyImport, 'mysheet.xlsx', 's3');
```

and uploaded 'mysheet.xlsx' file in s3 bucket path as 'storage/frameworks/laravel-excel/mysheet.xlsx'

Still I am getting same error. As I understand correctly, after this change, system is getting the file from S3 location, but still trying to keep the file temporary in default location, that is readonly in Lambda.

Laravel Version: 8
Laravel-Excel: 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a lot of articles and forums, I found the solution.

Main reason of above error is due to the readonly mode of AWS Lambda. By default the excel is trying to upload in the root folder, that is readonly in the case of Lambda and it fails.

Only editable path supported by Lambda is /tmp

The solution is to specify the path in config/excel.php

```
return [

'temporary_files' => [
    'local_path' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
],
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, by default the root path where your Laravel application runs is "read-only", Lambda provides a temporary directory where it is possible to perform write operations.

In your case the solution is adequate, but keep in mind that you can have the same problem with other services such as session and cache using the "file" driver.

You can write this little block of code inside your `AppServiceProvider.php` to change the "storage_path" that points to the root folder where your application lives.

```php
public function register()
{
  // Valid only in the production evironment.
  if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
    $this->app->instance('path.storage', '/tmp/laravel/storage');
  }
}
```